# YAML Mapping exception on Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, doctrine, yaml, relation

I created my database and tables using phpMyAdmin. I setup the relations there aswell.

I then wanted to get Doctrine 2 to create the YAML files for me by do this command:

> php doctrine orm:convert-mapping
>   --from-database yml /path/to/fixtures/schema

And it created the *.dcm.yml files and looks ok. So I needed to make entities by doing this:

> php doctrine orm:generate-entities
>   /path/to/models

I get this error however:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Class Callers\dcm is not a valid
>   entity or mapped super class.

I added the -v flag and got this:

> Exception trace:  () at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:137
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/YamlDriver.php:55
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver->loadMetadataForClass()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:282
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:176
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:123
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/GenerateEntitiesCommand.php:101
>   Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateEntitiesCommand->execute()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:150
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:187
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/classes/doctrine/Doctrine/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:113
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
>   at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/bin/doctrine.php:40
>   include() at
>   /Users/me/Sites/project/modules/doctrine2/bin/doctrine:4

I am trying to get Doctrine 2 to work with MySQL relationships as a module of Kohana. Thought I would start with getting Doctrine to work as that's really the harder part.

Here is the YAML file it created:

```
Callers:
  type: entity
  table: callers
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    firstname:
      type: string
      length: 75
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    lastname:
      type: string
      length: 75
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    company:
      type: string
      length: 75
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    email:
      type: string
      length: 150
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    datecreated:
      type: datetime
      nullable: false
    dateupdated:
      type: datetime
      nullable: false
    address1:
      type: string
      length: 150
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    address2:
      type: string
      length: 150
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    city:
      type: string
      length: 100
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    state:
      type: string
      length: 50
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
    zip:
      type: string
      length: 10
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
```

So what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error happen to me. Make sure your .dcm.yml file is named Callers.dcl.yml and not callers.dcl.yml. The upper case first letter is important and must match your class name.